# How do I remove an rpm package with chef along with dependencies?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rpm

How do I remove an rpm package in a recipe when it could have some dependencies associated with it?

My use case is that I am a tester, and use chef to setup / upgrade / downgrade my testing environments. In order to ensure I have a clean environment when upgrading, I remove the app that is installed using:

```
rpm_package rpmName do
    action[:remove]
end
```

However, sometimes my environment also installs an extra "plugin" rpm that is dependent on the main app's rpm. When I run chef and it runs the remove main app's package command, chef fails because of the dependency issue:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
rpm  -e <main app> returned 1, expected 0
```

And on the server:

```
[root@qa ~]# rpm  -e <main app>
error: Failed dependencies:
<main app> >= X.x.x is needed by (installed) <plugin rpm>
```

I looked at the Chef docs for rpm_package, but didn't come across anything that could help me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there chef rules (or whatever they are called) that use yum? Asking yum to remove a package that is a dependency of another package will ask to remove the dependent package as well and only fails if told not to.

Comment: Chef uses recipes (probably what you are referring to), and yes, there is a yum resource. However, that would require a bunch of extra effort maintaining a yum repo somewhere, which is a project we don't have time for, thus why we're using RPMs.

Comment: @bbbco You don't need a yum repo to use 'yum remove'.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that. I tried it and it seems to work. `yum remove` it is!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a by-product of RPM, not Chef. You'll need to query RPM to figure out which packages use it as a dependency and uninstall them first. It's like reverse dependency management.

Comment: Ok, any idea how to pull the RPMs and then iterate over them using chef code?